# How to make div box actually touching the side of the browser as mine has a gap?

Tags: css, html

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="footer" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
Footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

As [you can see in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XwKQ/1/) the footer at the bottom has a slight gap on the left.

I want it to be 100% at the bottom so how do I achieve this thus eliminating the gap on the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the following CSS style:

```
body, html
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

And you just got rid of the gap.

Comment: Sorry Im new to Css, i copied this into my css file but its still the same. What do I do? Sorry!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add the margin. It's above in the answer. You probably have a horizontal scrollbar now, that's because you've got a one pixel border on your div. If you reduce it to a border-top you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I use those on each site to minimize browser incompatibilities as well:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```